# Three.js - Raycaster/clicking on objects in 3D space

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is the use of Raycaster required to click on something in the three.js 3D space? Let's say I click on a cube, and that certain cube is supposed to move/change color for example.

Version 71

Comment: Built-in THREE.Raycaster fits for it as it returns to you sorted by distance array of objects in scene when you hit with ray. But it's not required since you can implement whatever you want for it. You could start to play with it from threejs docs.

Comment: I think you should consider reformulating your question. No, it's not required, but why are you asking? Are you looking for an alternative? If so, what's the problem with the Raycaster that the alternative needs to solve? Or are you perhaps looking for an example of *how* to use the Raycaster?

Comment: How to use it; more specifically how to move something based on if I clicked it or not. I am having trouble with it. It has been posted here.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024688/raycaster-how-to-move-the-mesh-that-i-clicked-on)