# Raycaster - How to move the mesh that I clicked on

Tags: javascript, three.js, tween.js

I am trying to click on an object, which is a mesh. For instance, if I click on apple, I want the apple to move in the specific coordinates. Right now, I set the clickedObject as apple for right now.

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);

var objects = new Array();
objects.push(apple, orange, banana);
var clickedObject;

function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
    var mouse_x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    var mouse_y = -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(mouse_x, mouse_y, 0.5);
    vector.unproject(camera);
    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position,
            vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());

    console.log("on mouse down event handler");
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );
    if (intersects.length > 0) {

        // the first one is the object we'll be moving around
        clickedObject = intersects[0].object;
        // and calculate the offset
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(referencePlane);
        if(clickedObject === apple) {
            var tween2 = new TWEEN.Tween(apple.position)
                    .to({ x: 0}, 100)
                    .start();
            animate();
        }
        if(clickedObject === orange) {
            var tween2 = new TWEEN.Tween(orange.position)
                    .to({ x: 0}, 100)
                    .start();
            animate();
        }
        if(clickedObject === banana) {
            var tween2 = new TWEEN.Tween(banana.position)
                    .to({ x: 0}, 100)
                    .start();
            animate();
        }
    }
}
```

It's kind of working. But it also animates "orange" too, when I click on the orange mesh. Am I doing this correctly? I want to animate all objects (not at the same time), depending if I click on that specific one.

Comment: What are `orange`, `banana`, `apple`?

Comment: They are meshes not defined in the code that I posted; shapes essentially - like var apple = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(.5, .5, .5), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xFF0000}));